# How to draw the trajectory of a mesh with threejs

Tags: three.js, physijs

I'm trying to draw the trajectory of a projectile motion with threejs. Which is the best way to do that? Here is an example of it:
http://www.physgl.org/index.php/welcome/logout Try the projectile motion demo and click run.

I thought of drawing a second mesh that follows the previous movement by obtaining the position of the mesh as it's moving, but that did not work. This is what I tried (this code) to get the position of the object moving:

box.geometry.computeBoundingBox();

```
    var boundingBox = box.geometry.boundingBox;

    var position = new THREE.Vector3();
    position.subVectors( boundingBox.max, boundingBox.min );
    position.multiplyScalar( 0.5 );
    position.add( boundingBox.min );

    position.applyMatrix4( box.matrixWorld );

    console.log(position.x + ',' + position.y + ',' + position.z);
```

Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried, and ask a specific question.

Comment: To set `mesh2`'s position, all you have to do is `mesh2.position.getPositionFromMatrix( projectile.matrixWorld );`

Comment: What do you want? Why do you need a second mesh? Try just get and set the position of the ball?

Comment: I tried to dra the trajectory of a projectile, like the example, I don't which is the best way to achieve that, I just thought to create a ball that follows the projectile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about tracking a trajectory. Here, I will show you some alternatives to your desired behavior, in addition to its solution.

## Solution A: Mark each step

In your Physijs application, you should have a `scene.simulate` call and an event listener when the [update has finished](https://github.com/chandlerprall/Physijs/blob/master/examples/compound.html#L45), so that you can loop through physics separately from the rendering process. It shouldn't be too hard to add a little extra code to place a marker of some sort every step into your scene, which preferably doesn't contain too many extra vertices (i.e. not too complex):

```
var markSize = 2; // Tweak this to set marker size

var markGeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(markSize, markSize, markSize, 1, 1, 1);
var markMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "blue"});

scene.addEventListener("update", function(){

    // Generate a box where projectile was last moved
    var marker = new THREE.Mesh(markGeom.clone(), markMat);
    marker.position.copy(projectile.position);

    // Display position!
    scene.add(marker);

    // Keep simulation going
    scene.simulate(undefined, 2);
});
```

In this code, `projectile` is the variable referencing your projectile Physijs mesh. Note that you shouldn't format this for your rendering loop, as you might be using `requestAnimationFrame`, which stops calling your rendering loop when the window (or tab) goes out of focus. It won't be pleasant when some client does that and gets a messed up trajectory. Plus, this tied directly into your Physijs stepping, which makes it extremely precise.

## Solution B: Dynamic arrow

This is probably what you wanted in the first place. It creates an arrow which will show the direction and speed of the projectile:

```
// Constructor: direction, origin, length, color in hexadecimal
var arrowMark = new THREE.ArrowHelper(
    new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), projectile.position, 0, 0x884400);

function drawDir(){
    var pvel = projectile.getLinearVelocity();

    // Update arrow
    arrowMark.position.set(projectile.position);
    arrowMark.setDirection(pvel.normalize());
    arrowMark.setLength(pvel.length());
}
```

Yeah, that was kind of easy. Once again, `projectile` is referencing your projectile Physijs mesh. Just call `drawDir` every render call and you're good to go!

The `THREE.ArrowHelper` documentation: [ArrowHelper](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/helpers/ArrowHelper)